# CVS checkout ignore corrupted files

Tags: file, cvs, corruption, vcs-checkout

Is there a way to have CVS checkout everything and if it hits corrupted files it will just skip them and go on?

Comment: How is CVS supposed to tell if the file is corrupted or not?

Comment: Easily, it performs error checking on the RCS file.  On erroneous RCS files the checkout bails.  I'd love to know the solution to this now as I am currently dealing with the same problem.

Comment: @vfilby Does the checkout bail silently?  If not, what's the error message displayed?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to "[can I create a pre-checkout hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092834/can-i-create-a-pre-checkout-cvs-hook)" might help.

It suggests you can modify the [cvs_acls](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/*checkout*/ccvs/contrib/cvs_acls.html?revision=1.3&root=cvs) list to perform your error checking and block the checkout of files from the repository.