# Can I create a pre-checkout cvs hook

Tags: version-control, cvs

I would like to prevent certain users from checking out certain modules of code in my cvs repo. I have already implemented pre-commit hooks that prevent those same users from *committing* code to particular module, but I don't see any way to prevent a *checkout* of that same module.

Does anyone know of a way to prevent a CVS checkout of certain modules using hooks?

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/info-cvs@nongnu.org/msg07177.html) mentions the [**cvs_acls** script](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/%2acheckout%2a/ccvs/contrib/cvs_acls.html?revision=1.3&root=cvs), in the source code distribution of CVS, in the **contrib/** directory.
It could do what you are looking for.

> Ex. `TAG1`, `TAG2`, `TAG3`, `TAG4`, `TAG5`
>   checkout/update/export operation for `TAG1` & `TAG2` should fail. (`cvs co -r TAG1 mod_dir`)

The [original script](http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/%2acheckout%2a/ccvs/contrib/cvs_acls.pl?root=cvs&revision=1.6&content-type=text%2Fplain) is only for preventing commit, but it can be patched to prevent checkout as well.
More alternatives are presented in this [CVS FAQ](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/wiki/CVS%20FAQ#How%20do%20I%20control%20list%20or%20read%20access%20within%20the%20repository?).