# Putting a warning flag on a particular version

Tags: version-control, cvs

I have 4 versions of a file `1.21, 1.22, 1.23` and `1.24`. After a month of time I came to know that the version `1.22` and `1.23` have some errors in them. Now I don't want anyone to use those versions. One way to solve it is to delete those versions, but I don't want to delete them. I just want to know a way so that if anyone checkout those obsolete versions they should get a warning or custom message that "don't use this version, this version has some problems".

Is there any way to do this? Let me know, thanks.

Comment: Assuming 1.21 etc are tags, you could tag the real 1.22 with 1.22buggy and remove the 1.22 tag, or move it to a version which doesn't compile, or something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a CVS expert, but you could tag the bad revisions and then write some sort of pre-checkout hook (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092834/can-i-create-a-pre-checkout-cvs-hook)).

I'm not sure how one would go about implementing it, though. Or if it could work, for that matter.